# Get the image onto the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas

I need to upload the image onto the canvas, but the image keeps on coming beside the canvas instead of inside it. I made a code for that to happen but does not work. Thanks in advance.

Js:

```
//Link Canvas

var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = $('#gameCanvas').width();
var height = $('#gameCanvas').height();
//Car Image

var car = new Image();
car.src = "http://images.clipartpanda.com/car-top-view-clipart-red-racing-car-top-view-fe3a.png";


//Car x,y Position
var x = 220;
var y = 200;

//Car Speed and angle
var speed = 7;
var angle = 0;
var mod = 0;

//Keyboard Listeners

window.addEventListener("keydown", keypress_handler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyup_handler, false);


var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
    draw();
}, 30);

//Draw Car

function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //Rotate Car When Turning

    x += (speed * mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    y += (speed * mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle);

    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
    context.drawImage(car, -(car.width / 2), -(car.height / 2));
    context.restore();
}

//Keyboard Function

function keyup_handler(event) {
    console.log('a');
    if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) { 

        mod = 0;
    }
}

//Keyboard keys to operate car

function keypress_handler(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == 38) { //Up arrow
        mod = 1;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) { //Down arrow
        mod = -1;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //Left Arrow
        angle -= 5;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) { //Right Arrow
        angle += 5;
    }
}

function update() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    x += speed;
    y += speed;

if (x >= $('#gameCanvas')){
    speed = 0;
}

if (y >= $('#gameCanvas')){
    speed = -1.0 * speed;
    speed = 0;
}
}
```

Code That does not work:

```
var URL = [
    "http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/69386/69386,1162932792,3/stock-photo-lone-car-in-four-lanes-from-above-2128171.jpg",
];
var canvas
var imgs = URL.map(function(URL) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = URL;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    return img;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var background = new Image();
background.src = "http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/69386/69386,1162932792,3/stock-photo-lone-car-in-four-lanes-from-above-2128171.jpg";

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}​
```

Comment: im using this code, the image comes onto the canvas but then goes away.

Answer (score 0):

```
var background = new Image();
background.src = "http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/69386/69386,1162932792,3/stock-photo-lone-car-in-four-lanes-from-above-2128171.jpg";

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(background,0,0);
}
```